# How to pass state to React JS High Order Component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am using OIDC redux connector for user state. I have a few components that require authentication. I would like to use something like `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withAuth(Component));` and request data from state inside my authentication service.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { push } from 'connected-react-router'

export const withAuth = (Component) => {
    return props => {


        return <Component {...props} />
    }
}
```

Is it possible to get state in the render function? So I can check the user beinig logged in and redirect to the sign-in page if there is no user signed in?

BTW: How would I redirect? I have tried using `redirect-router-dom` and `<Redirect />` But then it complains about set state being changed too often ... But that might be my mistake. I get this error when I render a Redirect: `Error: Maximum update depth exceeded.`

Comment: The question is a little confusing. You're wanting to map the state props to any component but then pass that component to a `withAuth` pure component and ... access those props within that? Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: I am not trying to access props in the wrapper, what I just found is called a Higher-Order Component / HOC. I need access to the store, check if there is a user present and redirect to sign-in if no user is present. As this is basically the same for all pages I want a logged in user, I thought this is a nice way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to "decorate" your component with additional logic to handle an authentication redirect?

I suggest using a "decorator" pattern here e.g.:

```
export const withAuth = (Component) => {
    const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
        authenticated: state.authenticated // Or what you need to do to determine this
    });

    return connect(mapStateToProps)(class extends React.Component {
        render() {
            const { authenticated, ...componentProps } = props; 
            if (authenticated) {            
               return <Component {...componentProps }>;
            }
            return <Redirect to="/login" />;
        }
    });
}
```

Then when you need this you can do things like:

```
export default withAuth(connect(yourOwnMapStateToProps)(YourComponent))
```

Comment: I'll try this, it looks at what I need, and I like using the connect more then using the import.

Comment: I place withAuth after the connect, where it was, but this method is actually working quite nicely. I can now finish my code to check if someone is authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out, I changed the store so instead of returning a function, it returns the object. So I can load in all js files. It might not be the best solution. If there is a better way to get the store in code, I would love to hear about how to do that. The configurestore function is what I found in quite a lot of examples.

```
import { store } from '../configureStore';
```

Using `store.getState()` I can get the current state.

The redirect issue I am having is similar to: [How to use react-transition-group with react-router-dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56339365/how-to-use-react-transition-group-with-react-router-dom)